# Call to SetSystemFileCacheSize is failing in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, msdn

The following call to SetSystemFileCacheSize() fails, however it passes if replace "FILE_CACHE_MIN_HARD_ENABLE " with 0.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SIZE_T dwMinimumFileCacheSize = 1048576; // Exact number reported by SetSystemFileCacheSize.
SIZE_T dwMaximumFileCacheSize = 1099511627776; // Exact number reported by SetSystemFileCacheSize.

int result = SetSystemFileCacheSize(
    dwMinimumFileCacheSize, // dwMinimumWorkingSetSize
    dwMaximumFileCacheSize,  // dwMaximumWorkingSetSize,
    FILE_CACHE_MIN_HARD_ENABLE // Works if this flag is set to 0.
  );
if (result == 0)
{
  // Error is "5" if it fails.
  wprintf(L"  Error E2469: Could not set size of system cache, error %u.\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
  wprintf(L"  Pass.\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME privilege?

Comment: @Alan Stokes Excellent idea, I'll try that shortly.

Comment: Error `5` = `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` should have suggested you missing privileges.

Comment: I've posted a complete [powershell script](http://serverfault.com/questions/325277/windows-server-2008-r2-metafile-ram-usage/527466#527466) that performs both the GetSystemFileCacheSize and SetSystemFileCacheSize functions. It runs some C# code that is fairly similar to C++ for the actual kernel API calls if you'd like to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that dwMinimumFileCacheSize must be 64KB less than dwMaximumFileCacheSize, if FILE_CACHE_MIN_HARD_ENABLE is enabled.

Here is the fix:

```
int result = SetSystemFileCacheSize(
    dwMinimumFileCacheSize - 64 * 1024, // dwMinimumWorkingSetSize
    dwMaximumFileCacheSize,  // dwMaximumWorkingSetSize,
    FILE_CACHE_MIN_HARD_ENABLE // Works if this flag is set to 0.
  );
```